# Setting up indexes and analysing data in JUPYTER

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLc9X.jpg)Hi Guys, attaching a snapshot of my df.

I want to grab Vertical = *Recharge* which I am able to do. Now I also want *CR*(Contact Rate) for Recharges across the upcoming months to plot a graph which I am unable to do.

Would appreciate help on this, thanks !!

Comment: Could you please explain better what you want to do with "Recharge" and "CR"?

Comment: Hi Ed, I want to show what is the CR for Recharge across various months. Like Recharge, I have got various other categories for which there are different CRs. I just want to plot it to a graph deriving comparison across months,